# Запрос через связь eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста есть такой запрос:

```
select * from 
`users` left join `user_parent_child` on 
`users`.`id` = `user_parent_child`.`child_id` 
where `user_parent_child`.parent_id is null
```

данный запрос есть необходимость построить через связь моделей не используя методы builder такие как leftJoin..., чтоб получилось что то типа такого:

```
User::with('roles')->with(['children' => function($query){
      $query->whereNull('user_parent_child.parent_id');
}])->get();
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал таким образом:

```
User::select('users.*')->with('roles')
->leftJoin('user_parent_child', function($join) {
       $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user_parent_child.child_id');
})->whereNull('user_parent_child.parent_id')->get();
```

Все работает, но может у кого то будут варианты поинтереснее.